# Solving version conflicts

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, jackson

I want to use the library com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.ItemUtils in my project.For this I set the dependency to Maven-com-amazonaws_aws-java-sdk-dynamodb = 1.11.x
But when I compile the code I get the following errors:

> Major version conflicts for the following packages:
> Maven-com-fasterxml-jackson-core_jackson-core has 2 major versions:
> 2.8.x
> consumed by Maven-com-fasterxml-jackson-dataformat_jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.8.x
> 2.9.x
> consumed by Maven-com-fasterxml-jackson-core_jackson-annotations-2.9.x,
> Maven-com-fasterxml-jackson-core_jackson-databind-2.x

Can anone suggest any solution for the version conflicts descibed in the error.

Comment: find out which one you want to keep, exclude the other one

Comment: how to do this? im a beginner

Comment: if you are a beginner, you should start at the beginning, and you wouldn't need dependencies that could lead to this issue

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html